# Automatically add a tag for a Java Cucumber method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

Currently I'm writing tests with Java, Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber with IntelliJ. When auto generating a method we are required to add an @step tag above the method for our report functionality.

Is there a way for me to automatically copy the tag from cucumber to another tag @ step above it in IntelliJ when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create the method from the feature file?

For example:

```
@When("^I am on the stackoverflow page$")
public void openStackOverflow(){
    ...
}
```

Would result in:

```
@Step("I am on the stackoverflow page")
@When("^I am on the stackoverflow page$")
public void openStackOverflow(){
    ...
}
```